# Freeform Pro Hidden Fields and Notifications

Tags: solspace-freeform

Currently using Freeform Pro 4.2.3 to have people "apply" for a current job opening.  The form accepts their name, email, phone, comments, then the ability to either upload a file or paste their resume into a text area.  The form is wrapped in a {exp:channel:entries} {/exp:channel:entries} tag.  I've got a few hidden fields on there for "job_opening" and "job_id".  Both of them are set up in the Freeform CP as hidden fields, and have default values as follows:

Job ID: {segment_3}
Job Opening: {cf_jobs_short_title} (Job ID: {cf_jobs_job_number})

I want to use the Job Opening ({job_opening}) variable in the subject of my notification template, both to the admin and the person who filled out the form.  Example:  "New Application - Position XYZ (Job ID: 987098)".

So my notification template has this in the subject:
New Application - {job_opening}

Everything populates correctly on the form when I view source.  But it's not being carried over to the email notification.  I have never gotten the Job Opening variable to work, now today I noticed one of the other hidden fields is not displaying correctly (it was, and it's showing correctly in the view source as well).

A sample of my form is as follows:

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="jobs" limit="1" url_title="{segment_3}" disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"}
<p>Thank you for your interest in the position of <span class="job-application-confirmation"><a href="/{segment_1}/job-openings/more/{url_title}">{cf_jobs_short_title} (Job ID: {cf_jobs_job_number})</a></span></p>
<p>Please tell us about yourself by completing the form below.</p>
<p class="form-requirements">* Indicates a required field</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
        {exp:freeform:form
            form_name="form_job_application"
            required="first_name|last_name|phone|email"
            inline_errors="yes"
            return="{segment_1}/{segment_2}/thank-you"
            form:enctype="multipart/form-data"
        }
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
                <label for="first_name" class="required-field">First Name:{if freeform:error:first_name} <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle form-error"></i> <span class="form-inline-error">Please enter your first name.</span>{/if}</label><input type="text" name="first_name" />
            </div>
            <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
                <label for="last_name" class="required-field">Last Name:{if freeform:error:last_name} <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle form-error"></i> <span class="form-inline-error">Please enter your last_name.</span>{/if}</label><input type="text" name="last_name" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
                <label for="phone" class="required-field">Phone:{if freeform:error:phone} <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle form-error"></i> <span class="form-inline-error">Please enter your phone.</span>{/if}</label><input type="tel" name="phone" maxlength="14" onKeyUp="formatTelNo(this);" onKeyDown="formatTelNo(this);" onBlur="checkTelNo(this);" placeholder="Numbers only"/>
            </div>
            <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
                <label for="email" class="required-field">Email:{if freeform:error:email} <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle form-error"></i> <span class="form-inline-error">Please enter your email.</span>{/if}</label><input type="email" name="email" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 columns">
                <label for="comments">Comments: </label><textarea name="comments" rows="6"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 columns">
                <label for="upload_resume">Upload Resume</label><input type="file" name="upload_resume[]" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 columns">
                <label for="resume_pasted">Or Cut and Paste Resume Here</label><textarea name="resume_pasted" rows="12"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="{segment_3}">
        <input type="hidden" name="job_opening" value="{cf_jobs_short_title} (Job ID: {cf_jobs_job_number})">
        {embed="includes/.job-applicant-notify-recruiter" entry_ids="{cf_jobs_recruiter:child_ids}"}            
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Apply Now!" class="button small radius" />
            </div>
        </div>
        {/exp:freeform:form}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Is it something I'm doing wrong on this end?  Any suggestions are most welcome!

Todd

Comment: How are you emailing? MX Notify? Using the EE email class?

Comment: It's using the standard email settings in EE

Comment: Did you originally set this form up in composer?  If so see here for a possible fix: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/34278/freeform-email-notification-variables-fail-to-parse/34280#34280

Comment: If you want to add your link and suggestion as an answer, I will give you credit.  That seems to be the fix!