# Freeform Email Notification Variables Fail to Parse

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

Having trouble getting Freeform to parse variable names in email notification templates.  Some are working and some are not.  I've tried creating new fields, duplicating fields that are working, etc.  Any advice?

Looks like a very similar issue to those reported by Todd:

[FreeForm Pro Notifications](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/34098/freeform-pro-notifications)

[Freeform Pro Hidden Fields and Notifications](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/32819/freeform-pro-hidden-fields-and-notifications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first create a form in the backend, you must specify whether you want a "Composer" form or not.

If you choose "Composer" you can still set up your form templates outside of Composer BUT any field that you reference MUST be added to your composer layout or that field will not be available in your email notification templates.